# jquery - programmatically submitting form with multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form with two buttons. I check which one is clicked at the server side using the `name` attribute of the element in the `POST` data and do stuff accordingly:

```
<input id="reply" name="reply" type="submit" value="{%trans "REPLY"%}">
<input id="delete" name="delete" type="submit" value="{%trans "DELETE"%}">
```

I'm trying to add a confirmation box (using the Boxy plugin) to the click event of the `DELETE` button using JQuery. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $("#delete").click(function(e){
            Boxy.ask('Delete?', {'1':'YES', '2':'NO'}, function(val){
                if (val=='1') $("#form").submit();
            });
        return false;
    });     
});
```

Of course this code results in the form being submitted with the `DELETE` button's name absent in the `POST` data. Is there a way to add that data to the `POST` data or a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a namespaced event, unbind on confirmation, then retrigger:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $delete = $("#delete");

  $delete.bind("click.guard", function() {
    Boxy.ask("Delete?", {"1": "YES", "2": "NO"}, function(val) {
      if (val == "1") {
        $delete.unbind("click.guard").click();
      }
    });
    return false;  
  });

});
```

Comment: Tried on FF3 and IE7, it works without problems. Too good to be true, thanks!

Comment: Nice! Definitely need to be sure to test on all target browsers, but other than that...

Comment: Update: Works on latest FF, IE, Chrome and Safari, as well as IE7.

Comment: Why `click.guard` as opposed to just `click`?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to do this.

1. If it's okay for the button name to be GET rather than POST data, in your `Boxy` callback append it to the form's action as a query parameter.
2. Have a hidden field in your form, and then set the value of that field to the button name (or whatever you want to use to pass the command to the server) in your `Boxy` callback. I can't whip off a jQuery example (more of a Prototype man myself) but it should be fairly trivial to do. If you're doing graceful degradation (allowing the form to be submitted without JavaScript), sadly this would mean you need to check for both the hidden field (JavaScript was enabled) and also the button name (it wasn't) on the server side.
3. Use [#serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) to grab the form data, append the button field to it, and submit the result via [jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype). This isn't the exact same thing as submitting the form because it doesn't replace the page with the result; you'd want to handle that in the `post` callback.

Comment: The first alternative will not work for non-javascript submits. The third requires a little more (and unnecessary?) effort than the second one, which seems to be the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have your delete button defined in a separate form.

Comment: Yes, of course I can post the form to another view on the server-side that receives only delete requests. But is it the best way?

Comment: Personally I would handle replying and deleting in different controllers, so it would be the best of both worlds for me.